# Setting freq of pandas DatetimeIndex after DataFrame creation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Im using pandas datareader to get stock data.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
ABB = web.DataReader(name='ABB.ST', 
                     data_source='yahoo',
                     start='2000-1-1')
```

However by default freq is not set on the resulting dataframe.
I need freq to be able to navigate using the index like this:

```
for index, row in ABB.iterrows():
    ABB.loc[[index + 1]]
```

If freq is not set on DatetimeIndex im not able to use `+1` etc to navigate.

What I have found are two functions `astype` and `resample`. Since I already know to freq `resample` looks like overkill, I just want to set freq to daily.

Now my question is how can i use astype on ABB to set freq to daily?

Comment: `ABB = ABB.asfreq('d')` should change the frequency to daily with `NaN` for days without data. Also, change `ABB.loc[[index + 1]]` to `ABB.loc[[index + pd.Timedelta(days = 1)]]` inside that `for-loop`.

Comment: You should put that as answere

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try:

```
ABB = ABB.asfreq('d')
```

This should change the frequency to daily with `NaN` for days without data.

Also, you should rewrite your `for-loop` as follows:

```
for index, row in ABB.iterrows():
    print(ABB.loc[[index + pd.Timedelta(days = 1)]])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

ABB is pandas DataFrame, whose **index** type is **DatetimeIndex**.

**DatetimeIndex** has **freq** attribute which can be set as below

```
ABB.index.freq = 'd'
```

Check out the change

```
ABB.index
```

Answer (score 4):

If need change frequency of index [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is for you, but then need aggregate columns by some functions like `mean` or `sum`:

```
print (ABB.resample('d').mean())
print (ABB.resample('d').sum())
```

If need select another row use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for find position of value in `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print (ABB.iloc[ABB.index.get_loc('2001-05-09') + 1])
Open            188.00
High            192.00
Low             187.00
Close           191.00
Volume       764200.00
Adj Close       184.31
Name: 2001-05-10 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The resample is essential if there is no way to pre-validate the regularity of the index - big data sets from external systems always have error and blindly setting the index frequency is likely not safe. While OP knows the frequency ahead of time, this answer is more literal.

Answer (score 0):

Use .asfreq on the whole dataframe but it doesn't have an inplace argument so you need to save it an object.

> ABB = ABB.asfreq("D")

Comment: It is good to leave documentation links for further reading on the answer, and any code is in code blocks rather than quote block

Comment: This would overwrite any data within the dataframe to nans. You're meant to be reassigning index's frequency only.