# Convert np datetime64 column to pandas DatetimeIndex with frequency attribute set correctly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, indexing

Reproducing the data I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dts = ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01',
               '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01',
               '2016-09-01', '2016-10-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-12-01',
               '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01']

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(len(dts)), 'month_beginning': dts})#, dtype={'month_beginning': np.datetime64})
my_df['month_beginning'] = my_df.month_beginning.astype(np.datetime64)
```

And what I want is to set `month_beginning` as a datetime index, and specifically **I need it to have the `frequency` attribute set correctly as monthly**

Here's what I've tried so far, and how they have not worked:

**First attempt**

```
my_df = my_df.set_index('month_beginning')
```

...however after executing the above, `my_df.index` shows a DatetimeIndex but with `freq=None`.

**Second attempt**

```
dt_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_df.month_beginning, freq='M')
```

...but that throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Inferred frequency MS from passed values does not conform to passed frequency M
```

...This is particularly confusing to me given that, as can be checked in my data above, my `dts`/`month-beginning` series is in fact monthly and is not missing any months...

Comment: What about using a period? `my_df['month_beginning'].dt.to_period('M')`

Comment: hm thanks. This is probably part of a solution but apparently not the whole solution, as apparently a period index is still different from a DatetimeIndex with a frequency. e.g. the library I'm using downstream of this (skforecast) is still complaining that my new series with the period index "has no DatetimeIndex nor RangeIndex index. Index is overwritten with a RangeIndex."

Comment: what about [Setting freq of pandas DatetimeIndex after DataFrame creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41535322/10197418)?

Comment: I don't think you can have a monthly frequency as this is not a fixed frequency (months can have 28 to 31 days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could convert the time series to the specified frequency using [asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

dts = ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01',
       '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01',
       '2016-09-01', '2016-10-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-12-01',
       '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01']

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(len(dts)), 'month_beginning': dts})
df['month_beginning'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month_beginning'])

df.index = df['month_beginning'] 
df = df.asfreq("MS")

df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01',
               '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01',
               '2016-09-01', '2016-10-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-12-01',
               '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='month_beginning', freq='MS')
```